# I think I may have broken the rep cap

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, daily-reputation-limit

I just noticed a drop in my reputation. It turns out that a rather unconstructive post was deleted and took a fair amount of reputation I earned with it. Given the amount of reputation I thought to myself "surely I must have hit the rep cap that day. Why did I lose that much?".

Looking at the reputation earned on May 8th, I see the following:

> [image]

Seemingly I have earned 244 rep from upvotes only. Now, I have a sneaking suspicion that this might be due to a minor issue in the deletion process itself, rather than me going over the rep cap on that actual day.

Does anyone have a clue what has happened here? I'm not certain it qualifies as a bug or is something that needs to be fixed. Just a minor issue in the visualization I guess.

Comment: Wait for a rep recalc, or force one yourself if it really bothers you.  These issues usually sort themselves out soon enough.

Comment: @Servy: It was 20 days ago.

Comment: @Servy already tried that. Didn't change a thing. I think the deletion process might take the upvotes on face value and update history accordingly.

Comment: And the `/reputation` audit trail for that day agrees with the 244 score for that day?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, the deletion process completely cancelled that out. There are no such votes visible any more.

Comment: Then this is just a display bug, surely; the post is gone, you only see that list when the `show removed posts` checkbox is ticked, and the list doesn't take a rep cap in account showing you the votes that have now been deleted?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's exactly what I'm suspecting happened. Not even sure if it's worth fixing if that is the case. I'm just curious though.

Comment: @Bart You broke it, you fix it :)

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk Fair enough. Give me access to the system and I'll see what I can do. Haha...mawhahahah....MUWHAHAHAHA

Comment: @Bart I see you comments passing by everyday.. not sure I would if I could ... ;P

Comment: Random, wild guess: When the post is deleted and it triggers the recalc, it may just go one by one through the events in the rest of the day re-assigning the reputation that you're now losing for that day to account for the rep cap. Potentially, the system ignores the fact that the upvotes it's now re-assigning are *also* on the deleted post and will, themselves, eventually get reversed. So it re-assigns the later votes on that post as the earlier ones are being reversed, and eventually ends up reversing all 240 reputation since nothing else took over that rep. Pure speculation, though. ;P